# Mostrar los N terminos de una serie en Java

Tags: java

Hice este código, pero solo funciona cuando pongo numeros pares, si pongo numeros impares, el resultado es como si fuera un numero par :( Esta es la pregunta:
Se tiene la serie: 1 – 2 + 3 – 4 + 5 – 6 + 7 – 8 …
Realizar un algoritmo que permita mostrar los N primeros términos de la serie e Imprimir la suma de los términos mostrados.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ejercicio1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.print("Digite la cantidad de terminos: ");n=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Suma: "+getSuma(n));

    }

    public static int getSuma(int n){
        int suma=0;int resta=0;int total;int i,j;
        
        if (n%2==0){
            for (i=1,j=2;i<n && j<=n;i+=2,j+=2){
                suma+=i;
                resta-=j;
                System.out.print(" +"+i+" -"+j+" ");
            }
        } else {
            for (i=1,j=2;i<=n && j<n;i+=,j+=2){
                suma+=i;
                resta-=j;
                System.out.print(" +"+i+" -"+j+" ");
            }
        }
        
        total = suma+resta;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te refieres a algo así?

```
/**
 * Realiza la impresión de la serie, partiendo de n = 1, hasta m (límite deseado)
 * @param limit n termino deseado
 */
private static void nTerm(int limit) {
    /**
     * @param sum se almacenara la suma de los valores de x en el ciclo for
     */
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x <= limit; x++) {
        //Si x es par, se le cambiará el signo, se imprimirá y se sumará como negativo a la variable sum
        if (x %2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(-x);
            sum += -x;
        } else {
            System.out.println(x);
            sum += x;
        }
    }
    //Se imprime la suma acumulada
    System.out.println("\nSuma total: "+ sum);
}
```

Salida:

```
10

1
-2
3
-4
5
-6
7
-8
9
-10

Suma total: -5
```

En el código hice `sum += -x` para que se apreciara mejor cómo es la suma acumulada, pero la forma correcta sería `sum -= x`, arrojando el mismo resultado.

Comment: Si! Muchas gracias